# Why don't my eigenvalues for A*Atranspose and Atranspose*A match?

Tags: python, numpy, svd

```py
  import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import scipy.linalg as la
    A = np.array([[-5,-5,-1,0,0,0,500,500,100],
        [0,0,0,-5,-5,-1,500,500,100],
        [-150,-5,-1,0,0,0,30000,1000,80],
        [0,0,0,-150,-5,-1,12000,400,80],
        [-150,-150,-1,0,0,0,33000,33000,220],
        [0,0,0,-150,-150,-1,12000,12000,80],
        [-5,-150,-1,0,0,0,500,15000,100],
        [0,0,0,-5,-150,-1,1000,30000,200]])

    print("Matrix A is :\n", A)
    A_Trans=np.transpose(A)
    print("Transpose is:\n",A_Trans)
    prod1=np.dot(A,A_Trans)
    print(prod1)
    u,v = la.eigh(prod1)
    print("Eigen values of AAT are \n",np.abs(u))
    print("Corresponding eigenvectors of AAT in the columns: \n",np.abs(v))
    prod2=np.dot(A_Trans,A)
    print(prod2)
    w,x = la.eigh(prod2)
    print("Eigen values of ATA are \n",np.abs(w))
    print("Corresponding eigenvectors of ATA in the columns: \n",np.abs(x))
```

This is the output I am getting. For the sake of keeping the post tidy, I am omitting some of the outputs.

```
Eigen values of AAT are 
 [2.85018004e+09 4.52373040e+00 2.19731826e+03 1.84822781e+04
 2.46139762e+04 4.52427374e+04 1.01150754e+09 2.18234247e+09]

Eigen values of ATA are 
 [3.28219743e+09 6.70266037e+08 2.95889936e-01 1.23330275e+00
 9.79916827e+03 2.20387805e+04 3.06750605e+04 7.13857850e+04
 1.12278371e+06]
```

I thought about using the svd function but I wanted to try it for myself. However, it works just fine in MATLAB but not in python. Also, when I am inputting smaller matrices like 2X2 it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Include the output in the question.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I just updated the post.

Comment: given the shape of `A` is `(8,9)`, the shape of `prod1` should be `(8,8)` and `prod2` should be `(9,9)`, right?

Comment: @paul-shuvo, you're right!

Comment: Are you using the same variable in Matlab?

Comment: @paul-shuvo Yes, I did the same calculation in matlab and it gave me the correct answer.

Comment: I get matching Eigen values for the very same code of yours (Python 3.7.5): `Eigen values of AAT are 
 [7.43537826e-01 2.34542038e+01 3.78271924e+03 2.09014798e+04
 2.47115976e+04 6.84370164e+04 1.01280641e+09 3.62580354e+09]` and `Eigen values of ATA are 
 [6.04093589e-08 7.43537820e-01 2.34542038e+01 3.78271924e+03
 2.09014798e+04 2.47115976e+04 6.84370164e+04 1.01280641e+09
 3.62580354e+09]`

Comment: @SKPS you are also getting the same answer as Matt. I am running 3.8.1. Is this could be a problem?

Comment: I am not sure perhaps it could be.  @WarrenWeckesser should be in better position to address this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this isn't giving you all the same values is that `A` is an 8 by 9 matrix. This means that `np.dot(A,A_Trans)` gives you an 8 by 8 matrix while `np.dot(A_Trans,A)` gives you a 9 by 9 matrix (This is because of matrix multiplication rules).

There is no way for an 8x8 matrix to have the same eigenvalues as a 9x9 matrix since, well, one will have 8 eigenvalues and the other will have 9. This is even reflected in your update where one list has 8 values and the other has 9.

Comment: Afaik even though the shape of both matrices is not the same, one of the eigenvalues is going to be 0 which can be verified by MATLAB.

Comment: so, the number of eigenvalues would be the same, not the values themselves?

Comment: When I run this code on my computer I actually do get a zero eigenvector (well 9.35593752e-08) and besides having that zero eigenvalue all the other ones are the same. My results don't match the ones in the question when I run the given code.

Comment: @paul-shuvo,actually it's the reverse, the no of eigenvalues will be different (8 and 9 respectively) but the values will be the same.

Comment: @MattWerenski I am not sure how you are getting the same values. Also, I just ran the code again on my system and it is giving me the same output as posted above. Could you kindly post your output here?

Comment: When I run the code locally I get this as output:

Eigen values of AAT are 
 [7.43537760e-01 2.34542038e+01 3.78271924e+03 2.09014798e+04
 2.47115976e+04 6.84370164e+04 1.01280641e+09 3.62580354e+09]
Eigen values of ATA are 
 [9.35593752e-08 7.43537846e-01 2.34542038e+01 3.78271924e+03
 2.09014798e+04 2.47115976e+04 6.84370164e+04 1.01280641e+09
 3.62580354e+09]

Comment: @MattWerenski: Yes, I also get same answers for AAT and ATA. My output is comments section of the question.

Comment: @MattWerenski That's so weird. I am getting the solution that I posted above. What is your python version? I am running 3.8.1.